# Integration RequireJS in existing Angular ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, requirejs

I have a task to integrate *RequireJS* to existing large ASP.NET application that already has *AngularJS* code.

The page already bootstraps *AngularJS* with *ng-app='xxx'* in master page. I'm trying to create a new controller that will loaded by *RequireJS*.
In HTML I'm defining new *div* as following

```
<div ng-controller='someConroller'></div>
```

*someConroller.js* loaded by *RequireJS* after *AngularJS* has bootsraped, thus I got the following error:

*"Argument 'someConroller' is not a function, got undefined"*

The problem as I understand is that *AngularJS* has bootstraped, HTML is loaded, but 'someController' is still doesn't loaded.

How can I cause to AngularJS wait for controller will finish his loading?

Please note that I can't integrate routing.

Please, advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bootstrap your project only when someContoller is loaded, so do this:

```
require(['someController'], function(){
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['xxx']);
});
```

in your main file and remove `ng-app='xxx'` in master page. What this does, it requires someController to be loaded before bootstraping you project.

Comment: Since there is a lot of legacy code that includes other AngularJS code, I can't bootstrap AngularJS when someController is loaded.

Comment: AngularJS works with what's already loaded, it can't instantiate controller if there is none loaded. Since you are depending on `someController` loading, that's the only solution I can think of.. That's what requirejs is for - managing dependencies, providing modular entities and so on. In this case your dependency is `someController` so any code execution can be done only when this is loaded.

Comment: I would suggest either doing everything the old way, or everything in requirejs way. Using those two approaches together doesn't seem to work on my experience.